# Trimming trailing zero in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Below query is executed in command prompt:

```
var value number(30);

exec :value:='0.560000'  

select  TRIM(to_number(to_char(:value,'9999999999999990' || rpad('.',8 + 1,'0'))))
 from dual;
```

Result:

```
.566
```

Expected result:

```
0.566 for 0.560000
0.5246 for 0.5646000
```

I need 0.566. What is the problem in this query? Also I need to trim trailing zero irrespective of the value I pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is leading zero in your result, try this:

```
select to_char(to_number(:value), 'FM0D9999') val
from dual
```

Comment: Thanks you very much...

if :value is 55.5505000000 then please modify the format model as:

select to_char(to_number(:value), 'FM999999999D999999999') val from dual;

Comment: but in this case, this wrong: select to_char(to_number(99.999), 'FM0D9999') val
from dual